# Use wordpress 4.0 outside it by extending a class?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use wordpress functions and the `$wbdb` on a script of mine outside of wordpress,but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried:

```
require_once('./wp-load.php' ); // this is the correct path is tested.
class cron extends wpdb {    
  public function results(){
      $sql = 'SELECT sub_id,email,cate_id FROM co_subsriber WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY sub_id ASC LIMIT '.$start.',750'; // $start =0
      $records = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
   }
}
```

I get error

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for wpdb::__construct(), called in wp-db.php on line 578
Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::__construct() called in wp-db.php on line 578
Warning: Missing argument 3 for wpdb::__construct() called in wp-db.php on line 578
Warning: Missing argument 4 for wpdb::__construct() called in wp-db.php on line 578
Notice: Undefined variable: dbuser wp-db.php on line 602 and all other pass, hostname...
```

Can’t select database....

I need to mention that with

```
require_once('./wp-load.php' );
```

and using simple PHP, no OOP with classes it works fine.

So what class should i extend actually?

Comment: Read here http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

Comment: why do you want to extend the class anyway? just store it in your class in the constructor and use it.

Comment: @Napolux added `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` same errors. Also it doesn't say how to do it within a class created by you.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider hmmm...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you don't call the constructor of the wpdb class with the correct parameters.

You would need to do something like this:

```
class cron extends wpdb {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct( /* params here */ )
  }

}
```

But this is completely unnessecary since `$wpdb` is already instanciated in wp-load.php

Just do this:

```
require_once('./wp-load.php' );

class Cron {

  private $wpdb;

  function __construct( $wpdb ) {
    $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
  }

  public function results() {
    $sql = 'SELECT sub_id,email,cate_id FROM co_subsriber WHERE status = 0 ORDER BY sub_id ASC LIMIT '.$start.',750'; // $start =0
    $records = $this->wpdb->get_results($sql);
  }
}
```

Now you instanciate your class:

```
$cron = new Cron( $wpdb );
```